# Regular connection fine but SSL issue

Tags: ssl, nginx, https

I'm running my application on CentOS 6.4 with Nginx 1.0.15 and gunicorn 19.1.1. My application works fine if I am just using port 80 and not using SSL. However, when I attempt to add SSL to the site, Nginx redirects to https://, however all I get after the redirect is "web page not available" with no additional information.

```
upstream apollo2_app_server {
  # fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
  # to return a good HTTP response (in case the Unicorn master nukes a
  # single worker for timing out).

  server unix:/webapps/apollo2/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

#server {
#   listen 80;
#   server_name mysub.example.com;
#   rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
#}

# This works fine like this, but when I uncomment the above 
# and the below ssl information, I get "webpage not available."
server {
     listen 80;
   #  listen 443;
   #  ssl on;
   #  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/2b95ec8183e5d1asdfasdfsadf.crt;
   #  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/exmaple.com.key;
   #  server_name mysub.example.com;

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    keepalive_timeout    70;

    access_log /webapps/apollo2/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /webapps/apollo2/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias   /webapps/apollo2/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias   /webapps/apollo2/media/;
    }

    location / {
        # an HTTP header important enough to have its own Wikipedia entry:
        #   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        # enable this if and only if you use HTTPS, this helps Rack
        # set the proper protocol for doing redirects:
        # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

        # pass the Host: header from the client right along so redirects
        # can be set properly within the Rack application
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        # we don't want nginx trying to do something clever with
        # redirects, we set the Host: header above already.
        proxy_redirect off;

        # set "proxy_buffering off" *only* for Rainbows! when doing
        # Comet/long-poll stuff.  It's also safe to set if you're
        # using only serving fast clients with Unicorn + nginx.
        # Otherwise you _want_ nginx to buffer responses to slow
        # clients, really.
        # proxy_buffering off;

        # Try to serve static files from nginx, no point in making an
        # *application* server like Unicorn/Rainbows! serve static files.
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://apollo2_app_server;
            break;
        }
    }

    # Error pages
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /webapps/apollo2/static/;
    }
}
```

- I do not see anything in error logs.
- I have checked port 443 here and
  it is open: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/
- This is a wildcard certificate that I am using successfully on
  another subdomain on a different server running on Debian 7 with Nginx with what I think is the same setup.

What should I be looking at? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have also shown my iptables as certainly someone would have figured it out then. I'm no expert in this area, but there was something wrong with my setup that caused the redirection to fail.

I ended up using the example from Linode and now this works.
https://www.linode.com/docs/security/securing-your-server#creating-a-firewall